# How to add <script> tag in nativescript or pass data between webview and components?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I need to add a script from a CDN in Nativescript, can you tell me how to add the url in my component to use it?

I need this:

```
<script src="script.url"></script>
```

I tried in a Webview but the data doesn't get passed from my component to the Webview, even with the `webview-interface-plugin`.

If anyone can help me that would be awesome.

Comment: what does the cdn script do?

Comment: Consider providing more detailed info (e.g. where is the code related to `nativescript-webview-interface` and what data are you trying to pass from CDN

Comment: im trying to use the paypal-checkout.js script, because the plugins in marketplace doesnt have support on angular